# How to pass a child state to the parent state without using setState from the parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref

I'm working on a self-contained component with the purpose of using it in many different repositories, the problem I'm facing is passing some of the child states to the parent component to upload the data to the server. Let's take an example where we have a parent component (Form) and a child component (Input), but the child will handle its value and events.

**Parent Component**:

```
const Form = () => {
 const ref = useRef(null);
 const handleSubmit = () => {
   uploadData(ref.current)
 }
 return {
   <Input forwaredRef={ref} />
   <Button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
 }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
const Input = ({forwardRef}) => {
 const ref = useRef(null);
 const handleChange = (e) => {
   //set input data to the ref from parent
   forwardRef.current = e.target.value
 }
 return {
   <input onChange={handleChange} />
 }
}
```

My question is will this be a bad implementation? Will there be any downside of passing ref and use it like this case? The reason I want to use ref because I don't want the child component to re-render on every user event (in this case is user input).

Thank you for all of your inputs.

Comment: "I don't want the child component to re-render on every user event" did you test whether or not that actually happens before you posted your question?

Comment: So if I was going for doing a state declaration: [state, setState] and pass setState down the child component, whenever the child component call setState(value), would it be re-rendered? Because the prop is changed I assume? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: React batches state updates for performance. So if you are under the impression that your components are going to re-render for e.g. every keystroke in a text input, you are mistaken. Also *in general*, you are not going to get a good reception here for questions like this, for two reasons: 1. it comes across as naively arrogant "I've spotted a problem in a system that I'm unfamiliar with but that tons of people use, I must ask why everyone is doing it wrong" and 2. you don't start worrying about performance problems before you *measure* them. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your comment, for the first point, I don't really get it, I'm just worried if that's a bad way of implementing the useRef, for the second point, you're right, "Premature optimization is the root of all evil", I learned that in Uni, but because my previous implementation on this component caused slow updates so I just being extra careful. But anyway thanks for your input :) .

Comment: Not a problem. As for the first point, make sure you follow the prescribed path (i.e. the one in the official documentation/tutorials) until *something goes wrong*. Don't get exotic until you *have to*, and even then invest *significant* effort in staying on the well-trodden path. Doing otherwise implies that you are second-guessing the React team and millions of users (arrogance). Which is fine: people, even large groups of bright experienced people, can go astray. But in that case you need to pony up evidence, not speculation. Second reason is that if you do something weird I guarantee that

Comment: 6 months from now you are going to open that file, look at your implementation, and wonder "why the hell did I write it this way?". If you do something weird, *at least document why*. Then at least you'll be able to look back and laugh at yourself instead of cursing yourself for not documenting whether the weird thing you did was out of temporary ignorance or actually necessary for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, I will make sure to document my implementation down so that I can come back and look at it like you said, so you suggest I should simply just use the useState or use forwardRef like in the document right? Passing ref down like this is bad, uncommon right?

Comment: Hi Jared, I think you might get me wrong, but if I was going for [state, setState] and pass setState down the child component, and call setState in the child component event handler (onChange) then the child component should be re-rendered on every keystroke right? This is because whenever the prop change, the child will be re-rendered, it's a different case to batch updating mechanism of React.

Comment: Yes, passing refs down is usually wrong. As for the second comment, I think disconnect here is that you *feel like* you are asking just out of curiosity but the implication of the question is that we, the people *you* are asking for help, and the React team itself are idiots who never considered the performance implications of naive re-renders. If you are going to (tacitly) accuse us of being idiots you may even be right, but you'd better bring proof more convincing than "I thought about it for 5 seconds". *Stop asking* and go test it. You may even get to come back and say "I told you so".

Comment: Yeah, you got the point, thanks for your inputs Jared :).